# Wordpress wpdb->get_results :: can't fetch data

Tags: php, wordpress

I've wasted too much time trying to figure this out. I don't understand why there's nothing showing up. It's as if the row is empty, but print_r($results) shows otherwise.
This code is not echoing table_color_header value.

```
global $wpdb;

$table_name_settings = $wpdb->prefix . 'admin_user_message_settings';

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name_settings");

print_r($results);
foreach($results as $data)
{
    echo $data->table_color_header;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've solved the issue this morning. Since my table has an item for each row, I needed to go through each row's item name to find the value for it.

```
global $wpdb;

$table_name_settings = $wpdb->prefix . 'admin_user_message_settings';

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name_settings");

foreach($results as $data)
{
    if ($data->item == 'table_color_header')
        $aum_table_color_header = $data->value;
}
```

where I have an item called "table_color_header" and its value is a hex color code.